# wordpress can't connect to mysql

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

This is my first time to try wordpress

1. Redhat 7x
2. Php 7.2
3. Nginx
4. mysql 8.x

setting in /etc/my.cnf:

```
datadir=/data/mysql/mysql
socket=/data/mysql/mysql/mysql.sock

log-error=/var/log/mysqld.log
pid-file=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid

[client]
port=3306
socket=/data/mysql/mysql/mysql.sock
```

I can verify database connection in cli like:

```
mysql -u wordpressuser -p -h localhost
```

But wordprcess always failed at first step:

```
https://xxx/wp-admin/setup-config.php?step=1
```

with error:"Error establishing a database connection".

I have tried following host value:

1. localhost
2. localhost:3306
3. localhost:/data/mysql/mysql/mysql.sock
4. 127.0.0.1
5. 127.0.0.1:3306
6. 127.0.0.1:/data/mysql/mysql/mysql.sock
   no idea how to move forward now.

appreciate for any hits.

Comment: Is your user able to use correct database?

Comment: @DanielVítek yes, I can connect via cli with user "wordpressuser".

Comment: and when you connect, can you run `USE wordpressdatabase;`?

Comment: @DanielVítek yes, "use wordpress" and response is: "Database Changed".

Comment: I believe Wordpress dosn't support MySQL 8.x

Comment: @user1165759 I do suspect but there are many tutorials use this version. Anyway , I gave up it.